# Looking for a simple graphical notifier in KDE, invokable from bash

Tags: x11, kde, notifications

I am using Debian with KDE. There is a small bash script, that runs in the background. If it encounters a certain condition, I want my work on a full-screen IDE or completely unrelated console windows, to be interrupted with a notification.

Once I saw an app, the sole purpose of which was to pop a window of googly eyes right in the center of the screen, but am unable to find any such now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

notify-send is simple, all you need to do is call it from your bash script like this

```
notify-send 'some title' 'some message'
```

You'll get nice little notification pupup on KDE.

Comment: This is based on libnotify, and should work on most if not all Linux desktops

Comment: This works fine, but I had to complement it with the `xeyes` program to achieve at least partially the *large-red-blinking-square-in-the-center-of-the-screen* effect.